# What is the brand, period and manufacturing process for unusual style of wire mesh/fencing?

Tags: wire, fencing, steel

I have come across the wire mesh/fencing shown in the image at a residence in Johannesburg, South Africa that likely dates from the early 20th century.

I'm interested in finding out the original brand of the maker, the period of production and any information on the specific manufacturing process for this material.

It is different from regular woven or hinge joint fencing in that the material is much heavier, perhaps 2.5 mm thick, and is made using a technique that does not require a full loom, and locks each individual crossing positively in place.

A regular image search finds any number of examples of fencing, but none of the same style.

[image: Unusual woven wire mesh/fence]

Comment: Hi Pekka, this type of question is not a good fit for the Arts & Crafts website, as we focus on the making of things, not identifying artists and additional background information.

Comment: My question was about the process for manufacturing this type of material to try to understand why the process was no longer being used. I appreciate that modern welded mesh may be lower cost, but the threaded nature of this process provides much higher rigidity. The reason I identified the site was because I assumed it would get attention from people who had a somewhat more eclectic background and who could have information on a process a century old.  If you can suggest a more appropriate site, I'll happily move the question over.

Comment: Interesting. I would say there is a good chance this is handmade.

Comment: I had not considered a handmade construction. The uniformity of the features would make me suspect otherwise, but I will make a point of checking for identical tool marks on the wire to see if there were at least jigs used in forming the loops.